# Objective C to Android XML Response

Tags: java, android, objective-c, ios, web-services

I have created a way to test if a link to a live stream is active or not in iOS using the following code.

```
NSError * error = nil;
NSString * responseString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.calvaryccm.com/ServiceTimes.asmx/IsServiceTime"] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];    

NSRange range = [responseString rangeOfString : @"true"];

if (range.location != NSNotFound) {
    NSLog(@"%@", responseString); \
   // Handle active content.
   hiddenVideo.hidden = FALSE;
    hiddenAudio.hidden = FALSE;
    noService.hidden = TRUE;
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"%@", responseString);
        // Inform user that the content is unavailable
       hiddenVideo.hidden = TRUE;
        hiddenAudio.hidden = TRUE;
        noService.hidden = FALSE;
       UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                              initWithTitle: @"Live Service"
                             message: @"There is no service going on at this time"
                             delegate: nil
                             cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                             otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
        HasShownAlert = TRUE; //let the other event know that the alert has already been shown.
   }
```

The problem is, I have no idea where to start in converting this over to Android and I am looking for some guidance. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Start Here: http://developer.android.com/ , example instead of UIAlertView you will likely be using `android.app.AlertDialog`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know Objective C at all, but as far as I'm able to understand you are only reading result from HTTP response from server and parsing it.
To send HTTP GET and read response:

```
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);
    HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url);
    httpget.addHeader("If-Modified-Since", lastModified);
    HttpResponse response;
    response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
    String result = null;
    if(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200) {
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        if (entity != null) {
            InputStream instream = entity.getContent();
            //here read contents of stream
        }
    }
```